# AsParallel().ForAll vs async await

Tags: c#, .net, assincronismo, paralelismo

Quando usar `AsParallel().ForAll`, e quando usar `async await`?

Estou disponibilizando um exemplo com uma rotina de download e outra de manipulação de arquivo.

O `AsParallel().ForAll` tem melhor performance na operação de download em paralelo.
O `async await` tem melhor performance na operação de manipulação de arquivo em paralelo.

Se alguém puder explicar a diferença e qual o melhor cenário de utilização de cada um, eu agradeço.

Código (também disponível no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0jKW0M)):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Parallel
{
    public enum Actions
    {
        TestParallelDownload,
        TestParallelSaveFile,
        TestAsyncDownload,
        TestAsyncSaveFile
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                var itemAmount = 5;

                await Test(Actions.TestParallelDownload, itemAmount);
                await Test(Actions.TestParallelSaveFile, itemAmount);

                await Test(Actions.TestAsyncDownload, itemAmount);
                await Test(Actions.TestAsyncSaveFile, itemAmount);

                stopWatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Finish {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Err", ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static async Task Test(Actions action, int itemAmount)
        {
            string[] items = Enumerable.Range(0, itemAmount).Select(i => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToArray();
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            switch (action)
            {
                case Actions.TestParallelDownload:
                    items.AsParallel().ForAll(item => DownloadAsync(item));
                    break;
                case Actions.TestParallelSaveFile:
                    items.AsParallel().ForAll(item => SaveAsync(item));
                    break;
                case Actions.TestAsyncDownload:
                    foreach (var item in items)
                        await DownloadAsync(item);
                    break;
                case Actions.TestAsyncSaveFile:
                    foreach (var item in items)
                        await SaveAsync(item);
                    break;
            }

            stopWatch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"{action.ToString()} Call: Time: {stopWatch.Elapsed}");
        }

        public static async Task SaveAsync(string textToWrite)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\temp\file2.txt";
            byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textToWrite);

            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
            {
                await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
            };
        }

        public static async Task DownloadAsync(string name)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/2183169552/the-test-fun-for-friends-logo.png");
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, $"{name}.png");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Infelizmente, por conter manipulação de arquivo, o código não roda corretamente na *cloud*, é necessário criar um projeto Console .NET Core para executa-lo.

Comment: Pelo que sei o `AsParallel` é multithreading e `await async` é assincronismo, são coisas bastante diferentes! Recomendo a leitura do seguinte artigo: [Concurrency vs Multi-threading vs Asynchronous Programming : Explained](https://codewala.net/2015/07/29/concurrency-vs-multi-threading-vs-asynchronous-programming-explained/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como comentado pelo [João Martins](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112798/jo%C3%A3o-martins), AsParallel é `multi-threading` - ou seja, você está executando tarefas em paralelo usando várias *threads* - e `async/await` é assincrono - ou seja, a tarefa pode ser interrompida, liberando a *thread* atual, e continuará posteriormente, possivelmente em outra *thread*.

Então no caso das suas *actions* `TestParallel*`, você potencialmente estará utilizando mais de uma `thread`. Mas veja que há um bug nelas: por não haver um `await` (ou no caso de Linq/PLinq um `.Result` ou `.Wait()` em métodos que retornam `Task/Task<T>`) poderá acontecer do programa terminar e o downnload ou salvamento dos arquivos não completar...

Uma alternativa que resolveria isto e daria a senseção de paralelismo seria alterar para algo como:

```
await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(item => DownloadAsync(item));
```

No caso das *actions* `TestAsync*`, elas executarão serialmente em uma única *thread*, que será interrompida no início das operações de I/O e continuará ao final de cada uma.